# Fill in empty div with jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var username = getCookie("user");
    if (username != "") {
        $(".dropdown").append("<div id='uname' style='font-style: bold;'>" + username+ "</div>");
        console.log(username);
    } else {
        window.location.replace("../index.php");
    }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie("user", "EricF", 1);
checkCookie();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Ver. 1.0.0 - Dated: 2017-01-30 </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><div id="uname" style="font-style: bold;"></div><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="frames/help.html">Help</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="frames/about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

</nav>
```

Good Day,
With a process of setting a username via a cookie, I'd like to display the username in the navigation bar (with Bootstrap).
I have this code into the navigation bar:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Ver. 1.0.0 - Dated: 2017-01-30 </a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     <div id="uname" style="font-style: bold;"></div>
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="frames/help.html">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="frames/about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

In Javascript (jQuery), I have this:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var username = getCookie("user");
    if (username != "") {
        $("#uname").text(username);
        console.log(username);
    } else {
       // Redirect to login
        window.location.replace("../index.php");
    }
}

checkCookie();
```

I try to insert the username between the empty `<div id="uname" style="font-style: bold;"></div>` but it doesn't show... And, yes, the console gives me a username! 
Anybody can help ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you try using
  .append("<div id='uname' style='font-style: bold;'></div>")

Comment: `$("#uname").html(username);`

Comment: I did @thebluefox. With no success...

Comment: Could you please create an example snippet in your question so we can see the issue?

Comment: @Lee92, I just tried it but no success either...

Comment: Any error in the console? `.text()` should work just fine for what you're trying to do. Can you post  a snippet example here or on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've just tried exactly what you're doing with `.text(username)` - and it works - so there is another issue going on.

Comment: @doutriforce, I have no error in the console. I try to create a snippet, but it gives me an error because of the cookies... (sorry I'm brand new to development and Stack Overflow...)

Comment: Are you loading jQuery library _before_ bootstrap?

Comment: @doutriforce, Yes I am.

Comment: Your snippet fails because you can't set a cookie here.

Comment: @EricF, i have tested your original snippet (using `.text()`), removing the cookies parts to avoid errors, and it worked just fine as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/phgl3ju.png). You must be missing something. Try to debbug your javascript, step by step.

Comment: @doutriforce, Thanks for your help! Obviously I'm missing something here.

Comment: @EricF, no problem. Do you know how to debbug javascript code?

Comment: @doutriforce, I'm using the console in Chrome

Comment: @EricF, alright. You can also set a breakpoint manually, directly to your code. Just write `debbuger;` on any line you wish to stop on execution.

Comment: @doutriforce, Interesting! I'll try this one! Thanks! :)